# Nginx same config for multiple paths

Tags: nginx

I'd like to configure several paths within a site (such as /foo/ and /bar/) in the same way. To avoid copy-pasting, I figured I should use a single location block, but the only way I found for doing that is to use a regex, such as:

```
location ~ ^/(foo|bar)/ {
    ...
}
```

Is this the best way or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 5):

This would work, but I believe it works slower, because it involves a regex engine, another alternative you could create the config you want in a separate file and include them in each location so that it would be written once and could be edited all together, like this

```
location /foo {
    include foo.conf;
}
location /bar {
    include foo.conf;
}
```

Inside `foo.conf` you could write any config that's in a `location` scope
heres a random sample snippet:

```
root /foo/bar;
try_files $uri /index.html;
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but that means splitting the config into 2 or more separate files. I guess it could be worth doing for a very busy site, if it provides a measurable performance improvement.

Comment: also im not sure it will allow two roots, might need alias for the 2nd.